# Stop looking for the entry point at runtime in a DLL

Tags: windows, winapi, function-calls

I have an application which runs on windows 2003, window 2008 and windows small business server.

There is a windows call that I make to reboot the system.All the calls mentioned below come from advapi32.dll

InitiateSystemshutdown - This is fine in windows 2003 and windows 2008 but for some reason not working in Windows aurora

InitiateShutdown - since the above call is not working in windows aurora we used this call and minimum supported OS for this call is windows 2008

Now my application fails to run in windows 2003 since the InitiateShutDown is not present in the advapi32.dll on Windows 2003

I get a failed to find procedure entry point for Initiateshutdown  in advapi32.dll

I have already put a condition also so that the proper function calls are called with respect to the windows version.

Is there way to stop looking for the entry point in the dll when the application launches.The condition will make sure that the proper function call are called?

OR

I should be asking Microsoft why the old call InitiateSystemshutdown is not working properly ?

Comment: Use LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress instead.

Comment: You don't need to ask MS anything. All you need to do is read the documentation which states clearly that is was added in Vista/2008. Learn to use MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use GetProcAddress and set your preprocessor variables for the earlier version of Windows.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745(VS.85).aspx#setting_winver_or__win32_winnt

Basically, you should:

1. Set WINVER to the earliest version of Windows you must support so you don't accidentally use something newer.
2. Some API calls and definitions won't work anymore (like InitiateShutdown in your case) in your code, because they aren't included by header files.  For these, you must use them dynamically.  Typically you use the GetProcAddress API and use a "typedef" to define the function's signature (since it isn't in the header files you're including anymore).  An example is here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx.  In your case you would use the InitiateShutdown API instead of the given GetNativeSystemInfo.  If the call to GetProcAddress fails then you can assume that the API is not supported on that version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Rather that *explicitly* calling that function in your code (such that your app will fail to load if the function can't be loaded from the expected DLL), call it implicitly via LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

Do a "LoadLibrary" on advapi32.dll.  And then call GetProcAddress for "InitiateShutdown".  Fail gracefully if the function doesn't exist, otherwise cast it to an appropriate function pointer and 
invoke it.

```
typedef DWORD (WINAPI *InitiateSystemShutdownTypeA) (char*, char*, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD);
typedef DWORD (WINAPI *InitiateSystemShutdownTypeW) (wchar_t*, wchar_t*, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD);

InitiateShutdownTypeA func = NULL;
HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("advapi32.dll"); 
if (hMod)
    func = (InitiateShutdownTypeA)GetProcAddress("InitiateShutdownW");

if (func)
    func(pwszMachineName, pwszMessage, dwGracePeriod, dwFlags, dwReason);
```

Comment: Nitpicking, but it's best to copy/paste the function typedef out of the Windows header file.  For example, using LPSTR instead of char*.

Comment: Right, but either way, he has to be explicit about calling GetProcAddress for the **A**nsi or **W**ide version of the API. So I figured it would be better to explicit about the real type of character string pointer in the typedef.  LPTSTR could be incorrect if he intends to call the ANSI version.

Comment: LPTSTR would indeed be incorrect due to the issue you describe.  LPSTR is ANSI, and LPWSTR is Unicode (wide character).  These are what are used in the headers for any function in the API with strings.  I prefer to look up the definition for InitiateShutdownW in the header, and copy/paste the return value and parameters to my typedef.  In this case, it would be (LPWSTR, LPWSTR, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD).  The headers don't use LPTSTR.  This way, I can be certain that I get the parameters right without making any mistakes!  Important for those more complicated API calls.